# Building libcurl on Visual Studio without threads for name resolving

Tags: visual-studio-2015, libcurl

I'm currently in the process of building libcurl on Visual Studio 2015. However, the [FAQ](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Does_libcurl_use_threads) states this:

> libcurl will potentially internally use threads for name resolving, if it was built to work like that

Now, I know that on linux using `./configure --disable-thread`, this would make libcurl not use any thread for the name resolving. Going through the documentation, I didn't see anything concerning a flag for Visual Studio. They do mention that the configure utility is not available on Windows but nothing concerning a thread disabling option.

But is there a similar flag for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do that by defining `USE_SYNC_DNS` or editing `lib/config-win32.h` in the curl source tree. See [the section](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/config-win32.h#L669-L672) that looks like:

```
#if !defined(USE_SYNC_DNS) && !defined(USE_ARES) && \
    !defined(USE_THREADS_WIN32)
#  define USE_THREADS_WIN32 1
#endif
```

Do note that by disabling the thread-using code for this purpose, you will not be able to timeout or otherwise abort libcurl's operations during name resolves.

Comment: This seems to work. Yes I know I will not be able to timeout. Thanks for the info and warning.